# Finding the index of a list

Tags: python, list, while-loop

My function gives the error ("IndexError: list index out of range"), and I'm not to sure why, even first putting i = 0. My code is to print the index of the first element that is equal to the target value and if it doesn't equal anything in the list then index = -1. (Using While loop)

Function

```
def yareyare(list_g, list_size, target):
found = False
i = 0
while i < list_size or not found:
    if target == list_g[i]:
        found = True
        result = i
    else:
        i += 1
if not found:
    result = -1
print("The index is {}".format(result))
```

Main

```
# Imports
from index import yareyare

# Inputs
list_g = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list_size = len(list_g)
target = str(input("What is the target value(1-10): "))

#
yareyare(list_g, list_size, target)
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: @ "if target == list_g[i]:"

Comment: And why are you passing in the list size? Just use `len`.

Comment: And have you tried debugging it?

Comment: it runs until I enter the target value

Comment: Two problems: You're passing "target" as a string so you're never gonna get a match with the numbers in the list. Also your loop condition should be "i < list_size **and** not found" If you use "or" the loop will run if either of the conditions are true so you'll eventually go out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two simple errors in the code.

First, the boolean logic of the while loop should be `and` not `or` because it allows it to loop forever since found doesn't become `True` until the target is found.

Second, you need to convert target to an `int` not an `str`

It should work after that.

Comment: You're also the hero

Answer (score 1):

`while i < list_size or not found:` is the culprit. As long as `found` is false, the loop continues even if it ran out of list entries. That said, the entire code seems very clumsy; a Python approach would normally use list.index, or for more verbosity, a for loop with enumerate and an else clause.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this code. I am going to try and fix your errors while changing as little of your original code as possible. There are some things that you are doing that will work that I would advise against, like passing the list length as a parameter rather than using `len` and using a while loop for this at all.

Your first issue is that target is a string while the goals you compare it to are ints. That means this:

```
target == list_g[i]
```

Will never be true. It must be changed to:

```
int(target) == list_g[i]
```

Your second problem is that you are looping while `i < list_size` OR `found` is false. When you find a match, you set `found` to false but you never increment `i`. This means that `i` will always stay at the same value and therefore it will always equal `list_g[i]` so you will never increment it. Since `i` is always less than the list length `i < list_size or not found` will always be true and you will be trapped in an infinite loop. You should change the `or` to an `and`.

Here is your function with the fixes:

```
def yareyare(list_g, list_size, target):
    found = False
    i = 0
    while i < list_size and not found:
        if int(target) == list_g[i]:
            found = True
            result = i
        else:
            i += 1
        if not found:
            result = -1
        print("The index is {}".format(result))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, those two fixes were definitely the problem with my code